# Pulling and pushing images on Github actions fails

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, github-packages, testdriven.io, github-container-registry

I'm following the testdriven.io course [Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker](https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/continuous-integration/)

I'm at the end of the Continuous integration chapter, I just pushed a [pull request](https://github.com/gaylordmarville/fastapi-tdd-docker/actions/runs/4430375092/jobs/7772507121) with all the GitHub actions, and it fails.

My errors from GitHub actions:

[image: actions fails]

Here are my settings for a personal access token:

[image: personal access token]

I tried different things to make it work from extending the access token scopes to replacing docker.pkg.github.com with ghcr.io as mentioned by Github, without success.

Comment: You seem to be creating a custom PAT but in your workflow, you're using `GITHUB_TOKEN`. See https://github.com/gaylordmarville/fastapi-tdd-docker/actions/runs/4430375092/workflow#L19 and https://github.com/gaylordmarville/fastapi-tdd-docker/actions/runs/4430375092/workflow#L46.

Comment: Also, see [Permissions for the `GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token) and [Modifying the permissions for the `GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token).

Comment: Might be helpful: [Publishing images to GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images#publishing-images-to-github-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My personal solution

---

I managed to solve the problem, but I am unfamiliar with DevOps, CI/CD, GithHub actions, and Docker registries. Therefore, everything that follows should be treated cautiously.

### Add a new step to the build jobs:

---

After the "GitHub to login packages" step in the *.github/workflows/main.yml*, add this step:

```
- name: Login to Docker registry
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      registry: docker.pkg.github.com
      username: ${{ github.actor }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
```

Create a repository secret DOCKER_TOKEN, and paste your docker token.

> Go to your Docker account
> page and click on the "Security" tab to access your Docker token. From there, you can navigate to
> the "Access tokens" section, where you should see a list of your
> existing tokens.
>
> If you don't have any existing tokens, you can create a new one by
> clicking on the "New Access Token" button and following the prompts.
> Once you have your token, you can authenticate with Docker
> and access private images.
>
> To authorize your token, click on the "Authorize" button next
> to the token in the list of access tokens. This will grant the token
> permission to access the resources it needs to pull the desired Docker
> image.

### Optionally:

---

1. to fix the Github actions warnings, you can change: **actions/checkout@v2.4.0** to
   **actions/checkout@v3** and **docker/login-action@v1** to
   **docker/login-action@v2** in the *.github/workflows/main.yml* file
2. Due to the GitHub migrating from the Docker registry to the Container
   registry, you can also replace **docker.pkg.github.com** with **ghcr.io**. It
   will make the code cleaner and up to date.
3. finally, if, like me, you are pushing "pull requests" first before
   merging, replacing **ref: main** by **ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}** always in the *.github/workflows/main.yml*. It will fix a GitHub action issue that you may encounter in the Continuous Delivery chapter of the course